# How can I flip an image-button inside a Windows 8 Metro live tile?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, live-tile

I have some image buttons inside a Win8 Metro live tile (in a grid), and Metro makes it easy to animate the whole tile, but not items inside of it. What's the easiest way to do a "flip" animation on individual image-buttons (or at least images) periodically? Should I use [createPeekAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212659.aspx)? I'm open to using either C# or HTML5.

Comment: I don't think you really mean to say "live tile" if you think you've put image buttons in one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported. There are only tile templates that you can use. You can't do custom animations inside of a tile.